# The altair library graph is not displayed

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I'm running codes on VScode but the graph is not showing

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
df = pd.DataFrame({"x1": [0, 2], "y1":[8, 3], "x2": [0.5, 2], "y2": [0, 3]})
equation1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(x="x1", y="y1")
equation2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(color="red").encode(x="x2", y="y2")
equation1 + equation2
```

output :
alt.LayerChart(...)

Comment: In my environment, it was displayed correctly. altair:4.2.0,pandas:1.3.5

Comment: I thought the VS Code would display a square screen showing the drawing
But he did not, and an alternative method is
I set up a VS Code for data science
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/data-science-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your code
alt.renderers.enable('html')
for more details read - [Displaying Altair Charts](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/display_frontends.html)
[image]